# выбор и обработка div блоков jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, в верстке есть динамическое количество div блоков с классом `.our-services .col-sm-4`, т.е. их может быть как 1 так и 100, как мне написать небольшой скрипт (`jquery`) который выбирал бы все элементы с данными классами в массив, я сделал так:

```
$('.our-services .col-sm-4').each(function(index, elem){
    // в этом моменте я не знаю как перезаписать в этом же массиве ключи элементов чтоб массив начинался не с 0 а с 1.
});
```

далее я попробую подумать еще сам :) спасибо!

Comment: а зачем вам чтобы массив начинался с 1 ?

Comment: для дела! по большому счету какая разница для чего, я жду ответа и помощи а не встречных вопросов! а нужно это чтоб проводить манипуляции с определенными блоками из общего списка

Comment: ну скажем так, нумерация масива всегда будет с 0 и никак иначе. Может если бы вы описали поподробней что вы хотите сделать, я бы и смог вам помочь.

Comment: Как показывает практика, реализация, требующая изменений базового функционала языка, обычно так себе идея. Но мы можем написать отвратительный костыль, в виде, например, функции ```var oneArray = function(theArray)
{
    theArray.splice(0,0,null);
    return theArray
}```

Comment: @bonusrk костыль написать можно всегда, хотелось бы узнать что же хочет сделать автор, так как я уверен что для етого никакого ни костыля ни начала массива с 1 не надо.

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych, полностью с Вами согласен. Плюс я сильно подозреваю, что решением будет прибавлять/вычитать 1, в манипуляциях с домом(если уж ноль так раздражает )

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример с использованием уже предложенного в комментариях костыля. Однако, как и комментаторы, я бы Вам советовал не использовать такие решения, так как ВСЕГДА первый элемент массива будет иметь индекс `0`. Зачем самому себе накладывать ограничения в будущем? В один прекрасный момент Вы просто забудете, что у вас первый объект в массиве пустой и будете удивляться некорректному поведению кода.

```js
(function($, window, document) {

  $(function() {

    var yourArr = {

      init: function() {

        this.getArr();

      },

      getArr: function() {

        var divArr = [0];

        $('.our-services').each(function(idx, item) {

          var obj = {

            //если я правильно понял то, что требовалось, то вот выборка всех элементов с "данными классами..."

            div: $('.our-services .col-sm-4', item).context

          };

          //...и добавление их в массив

          divArr.push(obj);

        }).bind(this);


        this.oneArr(divArr);

      },

      oneArr: function(arr) {

        arr.splice(0, 1, null);

        //return arr;

        console.log(arr)

      }

    };

    yourArr.init();

  });

}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='our-services col-sm-4'>1</div>
<div class='someClass'>2</div>
<div class='our-services col-sm-4'>3</div>
<div class='someClass'>4</div>
<div class='our-services col-sm-4'>5</div>
```